# Why does my root Umbraco page have no Children only when it is the currently active page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

> I have the following page structure in Umbraco:
>
> - Home
>
>   - Device Management
>   - Resources
>
>     - Manuals
>     - Downloads
>     - Terms & Conditions
>
> I have a navigation menu as a partial in my Master.cshtml template
>   which is the base template of all of these pages.  In this partial I
>   call `Model.Content.Site().Children` to get all the "Device
>   Management" and "Resources" nodes then recurse to get any descendant
>   nodes of these.
>
> This all worked fine when all of the pages used the same Document Type
>   (`ChildNodeSelectionPage`) but now I've changed the Home page to use a
>   derived form of this document type (`CustomChildNodeSelectionPage`)
>   for an additional property and had to create a dummy controller
>   (`CustomChildNodeSelectionPageController`) in my project which derives
>   from the original `ChildNodeSelectionPageController` so that the
>   `Master` model still gets passed back to the view.
>
> This part also seems to work fine (based upon breakpoints being hit in
>   the original controller) but the problem happens when the view is hit:
>   now, for some unknown reason, `Model.Content.Site().Children` has a
>   count of 0 when on the Home page but yet, if navigating to the URL of
>   any of the child pages it's 2 (as expected).
>
> Also note that the Home Document still uses the
>   `ChildNodeSelectionPage.cshtml` Template even though its Document Type
>   has now been changed to use "Custom Child Node Selection Page").
>
> **Master.cshtml** (note: irrelevant code omitted for brevity)
>
> ```
> @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<Web.Portal.Models.Master>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <body>
>         @Html.Partial("Navigation Menu")
>       @RenderBody()
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> **Navigation Menu.cshtml**
>
> ```
> @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
> @using Umbraco.Web
> @using Umbraco.Web.Models
> @helper AddMenuItems(IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> menuItems)
> {
>   if (menuItems.Any())
>   {
>   <ul>
>       @foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
>       {
>           <li>
>               @if (menuItem.Id == UmbracoContext.PageId)
>               {
>                   @menuItem.Name
>               }
>               else
>               {
>                   <a href="@menuItem.Url" title="@menuItem.GetPropertyValue("description")">@menuItem.Name</a>
>               }
>               @AddMenuItems(menuItem.Children)
>           </li>
>       }
>   </ul>
>   }
> }
>
> //NOTE: This is where the problem is when called from the `CustomChildNodeSelectionPage`.
> @AddMenuItems(Model.Content.Site().Children)
> ```
>
> **ChildNodeSelectionPage.cshtml**
>
> ```
> @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
> @{
>     Layout = "Shared/Master.cshtml";
> }
> //NOTE: Irrelevant code omitted for brevity.
> ```
>
> **ChildNodeSelectionPageController**
>
> ```
> public class ChildNodeSelectionPageController : RenderMvcController
> {
>   private ActionResult Index(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo currentCulture)
>       => CurrentTemplate
>       (
>           new Master
>           (
>               content,
>               currentCulture,
>               new Company(0, "ACME"),
>               new[]
>               {
>                   new Company(0, "ACME"),
>                   new Company(1, "Jimbo Jones' Jimbo Burgers Inc.")
>               },
>               "Jiminy Jilikers"
>           )
>       );
>
>   public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
>       => Index
>       (
>           model.Content,
>           model.CurrentCulture
>       );
> }
> ```
>
> **CustomChildNodeSelectionPageController**
>
> ```
> //Exists only so that the new Document Type can call Index on ChildNOdeSelectionPageController.
> public class CustomChildNodeSelectionPageController : ChildNodeSelectionPageController
> {
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out all I had to do was manually republish ("Save and Publish" button on "Content") every page through the CMS and it magically started working again!  Prior to this issue, I did have to change the Content Type of the root page via the database which seemed to create a few problems (of which I'm guessing this was one of them).

If anyone's interested, I got the idea to republish from here: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/templating/templates-and-document-types/4585-Change-document-type

Comment: You can right click the homepage and publish from there, it'll give you the option to  publish all children

Comment: Just an update on this: I found that I actually only needed to republish the Home node but for some reason I needed to republish it twice in a row.  Every time I make structural changes to the Document Type it is based upon I have to do this.

Comment: So you edit a doctype and the changes require 2 publishes to take affect?